# Execute trusted script

Tags: angular, xss, html-sanitizing

Here is a minimalistic example of a component

```js
export class AppComponent {

  htmlSnippet: string;

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.htmlSnippet = this.sanitizer.sanitize(
      SecurityContext.HTML,
      `<p>snippet works!</p><script>alert("ddd");</script>`
    );
  }
}
```

and template

```html
<p>app works!</p>

<div [innerHTML]="htmlSnippet"></div>
```

All the content is rendered. CSS works as well if any.

[image]

Is there a way to execute that alert?

Comment: Why would you want to execute that alert in the first place? (Anyways, you can bypass the sanitization of the HTML with the `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` method: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustHtml)

Comment: I think add script tag to the template like this will not work you have only one option is to create a script tag and append to the template check this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just create the script tag and append that to the body of the component

```
  constructor(private renderer2: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let scriptEl = document.createElement("script");
    scriptEl.innerText = "alert('hello')";

    this.renderer2.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, scriptEl);
  }
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4z949z)

> according to this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4903#issuecomment-151073263) you can't put a script tag in the body of
>   the template because it going to be removed the only way around this
>   is to insert the script tag dynamically as above.

Comment: So, if I wanted to render a complex HTML page with styles and scripts I can use `bypassSecurityTrustHtml` and then find all scripts in that HTML using regex and add them one by one. Right?

Comment: do you have these file locally in your project ,because you can just add these to you project bundle , or if you are install them from npm is still the same case

Comment: @TarasHupalo if you just put the script and the style tags in the index.html everything will work fine that what angular team said about it just put the script tag in the index.html or you can include theme with angular.json styles and script array

Comment: @TarasHupalo do you still have a problem do I need to give an example about this ??

Comment: This approach can satisfy my need. Thanks.